# Hide header/footer when url contains a certain parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a multi page webpage that has a header and footer on all pages,
and I am creating an app than can view certain areas of the page, but I dont want to show the footer and header when I am browsing through the app.

When I access the page through the app the app adds a parameter to the url. like this:

```
www.mypage.com?inapp=true
```

What is the most efficient way to this with java script and css?

Comment: Can/do you use jQuery? I think it will be easier with that

Comment: on some pages I can but not all. so im trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = window.location.href;
        if(url.search('inapp=true') === true){
            $('header').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search the parameter in the url and hide the elements if he's present.

**JavaScript** solution test each param for more fontionnality

```js
var url = "www.test.fr?inapp=true"; //replace with window.location.href


if(url.indexOf("?")!=-1)//parameters exists
{
  var urlparameters = url.split("?")[1];
  var parameters = urlparameters.split("&");//store all parameters in array
  //loop on each parameter  
  parameters.forEach(function(item,index){
    var parameterName=item.split("=")[0]; //parameter name
    var parameterValue=item.split("=")[1];//parameter value
    if(parameterName=="inapp" && parameterValue=="true")
    {
      console.log("hide header/footer");
      //Hide header/footer elements
      document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.display="none";
      document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].style.display="none";
    }
  });
  
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

**JavaScript** solution for only test the `inapp=true`

```js
var url = "www.test.fr?inapp=true"; //replace with window.location.href


if(url.indexOf("inapp=true")!=-1)//inap = true
{
   document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].style.display="none";
   document.getElementsByTagName("footer")[0].style.display="none";   
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is ok:

```
var headerSelector = "#header"; // TODO: replace as needed
var footerSelector = "#footer"; // TODO: replace as needed

if(window.location.search.indexOf("inapp=true") !== -1) {
    $(headerSelector).hide();
    $(footerSelector).hide();
}
```

Comment: I did something like this, and it works, but dont I need to do this on all pages then? is there no solution where you can do this once and then the items are hidden, no meter where the user navigates on the page?

Comment: you could reduce the code by using localStorage to store that the user is in the app in a persistent way, but you'd still need an if statement and javascript on each page to determine to hide the header and footer if that localStorage setting is set.

Answer (score 1):

### Using PHP

url is www.mypage.com?inapp=true
so if you need to hide header and footer when 'inapp' is true

```
<?php if($_GET['inapp'] != 'true') {?>
    <header>...</header>
<?php } ?>

<body>....</body>

<?php if($_GET['inapp'] != 'true') {?>
   <footer>...</footer>
<?php } ?>
```

here header and footer are not loading at all but if you wish to just hide header and footer add css to display hide when that particular query string is set.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a style tag with the necessary style within. This would not have the "flicker" effect when the header is first rendered and then hidden which happens when you only do this after the page was loaded.

This solution is used in a Squarespace template.

Here is my code in plain JS since JQuery is not always available and outdated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.includes('inapp=true') === true){
  var style = document.createElement('style');
  style.innerHTML = `
  #header {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .page-section {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
`;
  document.head.appendChild(style);
}
</script>
```

Note: add this to the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [PhP shorthand IF](https://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples) to set two different classes, depending on whether you pass a a parameter (?hide) or not:

```
<div class="<?php echo ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "hide" ? 'hidden' : 'visible');?>"></div>
```

Then define some CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is pure Javascript, no jQuery needed

You can do it like this (don't forget to add **your URL** instead of `'Your URL'` in `if` statement):

```js
if(window.location.href == 'Your URL') {
  document.getElementById('header').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('footer').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Cheers

Comment: Although this will work, I think it will be better to be able to detect the parameter and check its value, then you don't rely on a specific url format.

Comment: Sure, for this you need to add your custom `if` statement, the upper code is just for specific URL.